# How to check a set of cells is equal to another within a range and return a given value?

Tags: excel

I am looking to do the following,
I have a set of values C1 and C2 which give me a corresponding K1.
I now have another set of values C3 and C4 which correspond to C1 and C2 pairs but not in the same order, and with some duplicates.

I want to know which formula to enter in the K2 cells to be able to lookup the C1,C2 pair corresponding to the C3,C4 pair and return the K1 corresponding to the C1,C2 pair in the K2 column.

See the example below:

What I have:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   C1  C2  K1      C3  C4  K2
2   10  6   15.6    5   8   
3   10  8   14.5    10  8   
4   5   6   13.8    2   8   
5   5   8   19      5   8   
6   2   6   7.8     10  6   
7   2   8   9.8     10  6
```

What I want:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   C1  C2  K1      C3  C4  K2
2   10  6   15.6    5   8   19
3   10  8   14.5    10  8   14.5
4   5   6   13.8    2   8   9.8
5   5   8   19      5   8   19
6   2   6   7.8     10  6   15.6
7   2   8   9.8     10  6   15.6
```

Comment: For which column ? Ideally I would like to keep C3,C4 columns as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function Sumproduct works for me:

```
+SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=E2)*($B$2:$B$7=F7)*($C$2:$C$7))
```

It is too slow for complex queries though.